# Adding columns of numbers in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file with columns of numbers:

```
 1   0.0    0.0
 2   0.0    0.0
 3  15.2    0.0
 4   7.0    9.0
 5   0.0    3.0
 6   1.0    0.0
 7   0.0    2.5
 8   0 0    0 0
```

I need to find the sum of numbers from row 3 to 7 of the right two columns. So for column2 i want to sum 15.2, 7.0 and 1.0. For column3 i want to sum 9.0, 3.0 and 2.5. I need to maintain the single decimal point format.

```
code:

While (<INPUT>){
    my @a = split;
    my $c2 .= $a[1];
    my $c3 .= $a[2];

    my $c2_string = substr($c2, 2, 5);
    my $c3_string = substr($c3, 2, 5);
    my @sumarray = split ('', $c2);
    #then loop through each element and add them up.
```

This doesnt seem to work. How can i maintain separation of each number while maintaining the decimal format?

For c2, wrong Output:

```
1
5
.
2
7
.
0
0
.
0
etc
```

Desired Output:

```
c2=23.2
c3=14.5
```

Comment: And the output that seems to be wrong is, what?  It's hard to replicate with incomplete code.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $x = my $y = 0;
while (<INPUT>) {
    my @a = split;
    ($a[0] >=3 and $a[0] <=7) or next;
    $x += $a[1];
    $y += $a[2];
}    
print "c2=$x\n", "c3=$y\n";
```

---

```
perl -lane'
  ($F[0] >=3 and $F[0] <=7) or next;
  $x += $F[1]; $y += $F[2]; 
  END{ print for "c2=$x","c3=$y" }
' file
```

Comment: @FlyingFrog `perl -Mstrict -we 'my $x = my $y = 0;'`

Comment: That would not give me the correct sum if i wanted to know the total only from rows 3 to 4. I don't want to sum all the rows. just specific range of rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @data;
while (<INPUT>) {
    push @data, [ split ];
}

my ($sum2, $sum3);
for (my $i = 2; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $sum2 += $data[$i][1];
    $sum3 += $data[$i][2];
}
print "$sum2, $sum3\n";
```

*Output:*

```
23.2, 14.5
```

And this one does not create an array for the entire file:

```
my ($sum2, $sum3);
while (<INPUT>) {
    my @v = split;
    if ($v[0] > 2 && $v[0] < 8) {
        $sum2 += $v[1];
        $sum3 += $v[2];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; 

my $infile = 'in.txt';
open my $input, '<', $infile or die "Can't open to $infile: $!";

my ($col1, $sum_col2, $sum_col3 );

while (<$input>) {
    my (@cols) = split;
    $col1 = $cols[0];
    $sum_col2 += $cols[1] if $col1 == 3 .. 7;
    $sum_col3 += $cols[2] if $col1 == 3 .. 7;

}

print "Column2: $sum_col2\n";
print "Column3: $sum_col3\n";
```

Output:

```
Column2: 23.2
Column3: 14.5
```